# First-order non-linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to solve the Bernoulli differential equation.

How to solve the following first-order non-linear ordinary differential equation.

$y' + p(x)y + q(x) = y^2 r(x)$.

Comment: This is a Riccati equation.

Comment: Your ODE is as $$\frac{dy}{dx}+Q(x)y+R(x)y^{2}=P(x)$$and it's the Riccati's equation and it can always be reduced to a second order linear ODE. You can read more https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html

Answer (score 1):

Substitutions or transformations can often be used to simplify such equations.

We have

$$y' + p(x)y + q(x) = y^2 r(x) $$

For example we can do :

$$y = \frac{z'}{z\cdot r(x)}$$

And then solve for $z$ instead. Hmm, maybe there is some sign error, but the idea is fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a sign mistake in your question **(Even if there isn't, this answer will lead you to the concept)**. I will solve with the equation
$$y'=r(x)y^2+p(x)y+q(x)....(1)$$
Now this is a **Riccati's equation** so there is a specific method to solve this (Just some substitutions)
Now consider $$y=y_1+\frac{1}{v}....(2)$$ where $y_1$ is a particular solution for this equation and $v$ is nothing, its just a function of $x$ i.e. $v(x)$
Also from now on in this solution, I wont write $r(x)$ or $p(x)$, I will just simple write them as $r$ and $p$.


Now differentiating the  2 equation above we get-
$$y'=y_1'-\frac{1}{v^2}v'....(3)$$
Now at this point you may be confused what's happening but this is nothing more than a substitution.
So by substituting values in equation 1 we get-
$$ry^2+py+q=ry_1^2+py_1+q-\frac{1}{v^2}v'....(4)$$
Now replace $y$ by equation 2.
$$r\left(y_1+\frac{1}{v}\right)^2+p\left(y_1+\frac{1}{v}\right)+q=ry_1^2+py_1+q-\frac{1}{v^2}v'....(5)$$
Now after simplifying the 5th equation you will end up with something like-
$$v'+v(2ry_1+p)=-r....(6)$$
Now this is a **standard linear differential equation** and you can simply assume $2ry_1+p=Q$ and proceed with the solution.

Also for further knowledge I will suggest some good articles and videos for you-

- [Given by Alex](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html)
- [A video](https://youtu.be/3heIoKDhN3E)
- [Another video](https://youtu.be/iQxkAs7tnpw?list=RDCMUCtAIs1VCQrymlAnw3mGonhw)